# How do I get results page links to behave

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm sorry if this isn't a general question, but, I've searched and can't find a resolve...
 I'm building a site where people can make posts. When the user clicks on one of their posts it will open a page displaying the full post (CMS style). I'm using the _GET method and the links for each post are like this:

```
"<a href='item.php/?iD=$iD'>". $row['iTitle'] . "</a>" <br />
```

This brings the user to the page 'item.php' and in it it shows the post which is brought via a mysqli prepared statement. This all works fine, but...
the problem I then get is that every link on the 'item.php' page now has "/item.php/" in it, which, of course, makes the links useless!

Example, the home link now says
        `examplesite.com/item.php/index.php` 
where is should just say
        `examplesite.com/index.php` 
This is the same for EVERY SINGLE LINK on that page! 
So, do you have any idea why it is doing this as I'm pulling out my hair??? Thanks :)

Comment: I have problems to understand your question. If you don't want to have the slash with the links, why do you write the links with the slash? That's not clear from your question. Also you've not shared any analysis why you should get different links here. "Pulling out my hair" is not a good analysis description.

Comment: I've understand his question. But I've voted you because I agree it.

Comment: hakre, i'm sorry you didn't understand. But two other people understood just fine and posted answers in under 5 minutes. The reason i used the slashes is simply because I'm new to PHP and obviously didn't know better! This is why I only use this site as a last resort... because there are too many people like yourself who just want to pick fault in other peoples questions instead of being helpful. The reason for this site is to help people after all isn't it? And seen as there were already two answers and an accepted answer then there's really no need for you to add your two cents!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you add on `/?` slash tag and than add query string `?` that notes to and pointed to `index.php`.

You should change your link like:

```
"<a href='item.php?iD=$iD'>" . $row['iTitle'] . "</a>"
```

You got like:

```
item.php?ID=1
```

For point to index.php you should change to full path or back it to root:

```
'<a href="/index.php">' . $row['iTitle'] . '</a>'
```

---

You have: `item.php/?iD=$iD` which means:

```
item.php/index.php?iD=$iD
```

If you change to: `item.php/item.php?iD=$iD` you got:

```
item.php/item.php?iD=$iD
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a slash before the query string here. This:

```
"<a href='item.php/?iD=$iD'>". $row['iTitle'] . "</a>" <br />
```

Should be:

```
"<a href='item.php?iD=$iD'>". $row['iTitle'] . "</a>" <br />
```